# Why does the return data 0 on STM32?

Tags: c, stm32

I try to understand SPI is work good or not. So I send some data from the another function. For example:

```
BSP_SPI1SendByte(0x7A);
```

And than if i debug my code:

```
uint8_t BSP_SPI1SendByte(uint8_t byte)
{
  while (SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE) == RESET); //wait buffer empty

  SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI1, byte); //send data

  while (SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET); // wait finishing send

  uint8_t data = 0;
  data = SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);
  return data;
```

}

After the debug:

```
return data=0
```

Why is the data value 0? How does this work the `BSP_SPI1SendByte()` function?

SPI_Conf:

```
 void BSP_ConfigSPI1(void)
{
    SPI_InitTypeDef SPI_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    // /* Enable SPI1 and GPIOA clocks */
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SPI1, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_5 | GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_4;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    /* SPI1 configuration */
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Master;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_8b;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_1Edge;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_4; // 72Mhz / 4 = 18Mhz --> ENC28J60 SPI OK
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CRCPolynomial = 7;
    SPI_Init(SPI1, &SPI_InitStructure);

    /* Enable SPI1  */
    SPI_Cmd(SPI1, ENABLE);
```

Receive:

```
uint16_t SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI_TypeDef *SPIx)
{
  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_SPI_ALL_PERIPH(SPIx));

  /* Return the data in the DR register */

  return SPIx->DR;
}
```

Comment: possibly related : [SPI_I2S_ReceiveData always returns 0xff or 0x00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078660/spi-i2s-receivedata-always-returns-0xff-or-0x00)

Comment: Probably because it is full duplex? When you send, data in the rx buffer is lost. It's kind of hard to tell what's going on because of ST's so-called "HAL" (wrapper functions around register access isn't what HAL means).

Comment: When do you set `CS`? Either there is code missing, or you are not.

Comment: This is include cs pin set and reset 
void des_enc28_writeOp(unsigned char op, unsigned char address, unsigned char data)
{
    unsigned char dat = 0;

    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_4);

    dat = (op | (address & ADDR_MASK));

    BSP_SPI1SendByte(dat);

    dat = data;

    BSP_SPI1SendByte(dat);

    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_4);
}

Comment: check out these guys:
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_1Edge;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams, that you haven't connect any peripheral, or misconfigured the SPI interface? Can you see the sent data on a scope (MOSI - pin)? The function itself sends a byte and simultanously receives a byte from MISO pin.

Comment: I added my configuration settings

Comment: Can you add some more information about your circuit around the controller?

Comment: I try to using enc28j60 with stm32f3

Comment: How are non-SPI pins configured? enc28j60 has reset etc. and it's probably relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Can't put this into comments. But I'll set some tips.
check out CPOL,SPI_CPHA,SPI_NSS(CS) firstly.

You are seting CS to be controlled by software, does your slave aspects to be controlled via CS pin or no?? Also , do you know how your slave SPI CPHA, CPOL registers are configured? If SPI slave has different SPOL,CPHA settings, it also may be a cause why it does not work. As I'v read in some comments you are using enc28j60.

Datasheet says:

"**Before receiving any packets, the receive buffer must
be initialized by programming the ERXST and ERXND
Pointers.**"
You should find out how to do it properly. Also that chip needs 25 MHz Clock Input , just to work. And maximum SPI speed it can support 20 MHz. Be sure you met those conditions.

Also it would be good to debug with oscilloscope. If you don't have oscilloscope try to initiate another SPI module at same chip(stm32) as a slave and set same CPOL,CPHA  and CS parameters as your master SPI has. At least you'll get a start with SPI from master side. Than read enc28J60 datasheet accurately and try to send packets to it when you test your SPI master. From first glance enc28J60 looks quite sophisticated chip.

Comment: I can't get any signal from the SPI pins with the oscilloscope. I'm looking at the configuration settings from the dataheets. I used the codes here as a reference. I can't move a dead end completely https://github.com/xukai871105/uip_freemodbus_tcp

Comment: You can't get because you don't have oscilloscope ? Or STM32 SPI does not work? For firstly try to setup SPI from STM32 side.

Comment: I have an oscilosope actually

Comment: try 2 spi module approach on st32 chip itself.